# Isn’t it rare to use ‘rare’ as a verb as in “Congress is raring at the gate on tax cuts.”?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

I found the word, ‘rare’ being used as a verb in the headline of today’s New York Times article – “[An often procrastinating Congress is *raring at* the gate on tax cuts.](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/05/25/us/politics/congress-ready-to-get-started-on-bush-tax-cuts.html?_r=1)”
It is followed by this sentence:

> It is a maxim in Congress these days: If high-profile legislation
>   affecting millions of Americans is about to expire, deal with it at
>   the last possible second. Both parties in the House and the Senate are
>   eager at the prospect of voting for their respective versions of an
>   extension of the cuts this summer, well before the due date.

As I’m not very familiar with the usage of ‘rare’ as a verb, I consulted with dictionaries online:

Oxford Dictionary defines ‘rare’ only as an adjective meaning ‘not occurring very often.’

Cambridge Dictionary defines it only as an adjective meaning ‘not common, very unusual.”

Merriam-Webster defines ‘rare’ as an adjective meaning;
1. marked by wide separation of component particles.
2. marked by unusual quality, merits, appeal.
3. seldom occurring or found.

OALED adds ‘meat cooked for only a short time so that the inside is still red' to the meaning of (1) ‘not happening very often, (2) existing only in small number.

Only Japanese publisher, Kenkyusha’s English Japanese Dictionary registers rare as a verb and ‘rare back’ as a slang meaning  “brace for action, rouse oneself for action.”

Is “rare” used as a verb very often as used in “Congress is raring at the gate on tax cuts,” or “US and China are raring at the immigration of a Chinese blind lawyer”?

Comment: Try to search for "raring"--it's an adjective, not a verb

Comment: @Yoichi: If you could provide links to the articles that form the basis of many of your questions, the additional context would save a step for those who are answering. Blockquoting larger quotes will also help your question formatting. I've edited in these changes as an example.

Comment: "Raring to go" is not rare at all.

Comment: @simchona.I was assuming ‘raring’ only as a progressive form of ‘rare. I found OALD registers raring as adjective, meaning ‘eager, keen, enthusiastic, impatient, ready, (informal) dying, itching, gagging.’ Readers’ English Japanese Dictionary also defines it as adj. “longing for stg. eager to do stg.
So I understood ‘raring’ in the above headline is adjective. Then a question arises: When we take this an adjective ‘raring,’ isn’t it missing an object (to do stg.) in the phrase -‘Congress is raring at the gate on tax cuts.’ In other word, Congress is raring (eager, ready) for what / what to do?

Comment: ＠Callithumpian. I've received the similar request from somebody of the site members. He told me how to indicate link. He said it’s easy. I followed his instruction, but it didn’t work thanks to my computer illiteracy at my age. I don’t know how to block the quote part, or change its background color as you did either. I know it save the answerers’ trouble if I can provide the link. I appreciate if someone reteach me 1. how to show link and 2. how to make larger block-quoting in the way I can do it.

Comment: @YoichiOishi: No problem. To show a link, highlight the text you wish to make a hyperlink while typing your question. Then click the icon that looks like three chain links. A dialog box will come up. Enter the URL you wish to link to and click "OK." To block-quote, simply click the quotation mark icon before typing in the question box. Alternately, highlight something you've already typed and then click the quotation mark icon. Good luck.

Comment: I've seen the expression "to rare its face." This means anger.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific word's usage rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *OED*’s elucidatory entry for ***raring*** is brief enough to post here in full:

> ## [raring, *adj*. and *adv*.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/238728)
>
> **Pronunciation**:  Brit. `/ˈrɛːrɪŋ/`, U.S. `/ˈrɛrɪŋ/` 
>   **Forms**:  see [**rare** *v*.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/158251#eid26678695) and [-**ing** *suffix²*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/95704#eid432506); also 18 **r'arin'**, 18– **r'aring**. 
>   **Etymology**:  < [**rare** *v*.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/158251#eid26678695) + [-**ing** *suffix²*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/95704#eid432506). Compare earlier [**rearing** *adj*.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/159041#eid26875404)
>
> *colloq*. (orig. *U.S. regional* (*south*.)).
>
> **A.** *adj*.
>
> 1. Wild, angry; excited, spirited. Also as an intensifier: great. Freq. in rhyming collocation with *tearing*.
>
>    - 1845   *Amer. Whig Rev.* Nov. 516/1   May-be he warn't in a rarin tarin tantrum!
>    - 1851   ‘G. Seaworthy’ *Bertie* ix. 105   Ye see he's an all-fired, pepper and vinegar, hammer an' tongs, rarin' and tearin' abolitionist.
>    - 1926   B. Reynolds *Cocktail Continentale* ii. 29   And they sure can fix up a rip-snotin', raring, tearing, hotsy-totsy time, honey boy.
>    - 1942   J. Grenfell Let. 5 Dec. in *Darling Ma* (1989) 394   He was in raring form and told us some wonderful theatrical anecdotes about the Lunts.
>    - 1945   L. Lenski *Strawberry Girl* ix. 112   Hit stoled a bunch of Ma's eggs and cracked 'em,‥and made her rarin'.
>    - 2001   *Birmingham Evening Mail* (Nexis) 23 July 9   Teen idols BB Mak, the Honeyz and Point Break made the outdoor show a raring success.
> 2. Eager, keen, fully ready *to* do something. Freq. in ***raring to go.***
>
>    - 1918   B. M. Bower *Cabin Fever* iv. 42   ‘Yuh ready?’ Foster's voice hissed in Bud's ear. ‘R'aring to go.’
>    - 1927   F. N. Hart *Bellamy Trial* i. 10   Both sides are rarin' to go, and they are not liable to touch their peremptory challenges [of jurymen].
>    - 1935   P. G. Wodehouse *Luck of Bodkins* xv. 167   Keep it crisp, because I'm raring to go.
>    - 1957   A. MacNab *Bulls of Iberia* viii. 79   The bull was a toro de bandera, the bravest of the brave,‥and was ‘rarin' to fight’.
>    - 1979   *Church Times* 9 Feb. 9/1   We were at the starting-gate and raring to go.
>    - 2004   *Business Week* 26 Jan. 48/1   The highflier has been raring to get back into the big leagues.
>
> **B.** *adv*.
>
> As an intensifier: extremely, wildly, uncontrollably. Also in rhyming collocation with *tearing*.
>
> - 1854   J. M. Holmes *Tempest & Sunshine* xvi. 106,   I shouldn't have been so rarin' mad, if it had been anybody besides you.
> - 1892   *Atlantic Monthly* Dec. 793/2   Yer paw‥went off‥r'arin' mad about the spring.
> - 1909   E. Banks *Myst. Frances Farrington* iv. 49   They make me raring, tearing mad to look at 'em.
> - 1961   C. McCullers *Clock without Hands* v. 94,   I danced and sang and had a raring good time.
> - 2006   *N. Devon Jrnl.* (Nexis) 10 Aug. 6   Little Scottie is 'avin' some rarin' good fun.

### Citation

> raring, adj. and adv. 
>   Third edition, December 2008; online version March 2012.
>  http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/238728; accessed 25 May 2012. This word was first included in A Supplement to the OED III, 1982, as a subentry of “rare, v.”

Yet another case of good ol’ ***General Reference***; gosh, that old soldier sure gets around!

Comment: good ol’ General Reference; gosh, and such a long answer for that :)

Answer (score 12):

Oxford Dictionaries Online has this, which can be expected to be an extract from OED:

> **raring** (rar¦ing)
>    Pronunciation: /ˈrɛːrɪŋ/adjective
>   [with infinitive] informal
>   very enthusiastic and eager to do something:
>
> *she was raring to get back to her work*
>   *I’ll be ready and raring to go*
>
> Origin:
>   1920s: present participle of rare, dialect variant of **roar** or **rear<sup>2</sup>**

It's possible to infer what "raring at the gate" means: "at the gate waiting for it to open, raring to go."

*Raring at the gate* is an unusual turn of phrase; but the NYT seems to be cited here quite regularly for its turns of phrase.

Comment: See my answer below for the full OED entry. I’m not completely convinced what you have is a distillation of that, given that there’s no mention of **roar**, for one thing. Not that that matters, I realize.

Comment: "Raring at the gate" is **not** such an unusual turn of phrase. See Callithumpian on this page.

Comment: @Kris Raring *to go* is not unusual (as C notes). Raring *at the gate* is [**far** less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raring+to+go%2Craring+at+the+gate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 9):

*Raring at the gate* comes from horse racing. My *New Shorter Oxford* has this under *raring*:

> Eager, keen, fully ready, *to do*.
>   *Church Times* We were at the starting-gate and raring to go.

However, *raring* or *rearing* is also [used by horse riders](http://www.horsegroomingsupplies.com/horse-forums/rearing-your-opinion-new-video-pg-11-a-464099-2.html) to refer to a horse suddenly and disobediently raising up on its hind legs. This seems to happen at various gates apparently, not just at starting gates.

The phrase, or varying forms of it, sounds familiar to me and is [not as *rare*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22gate%20%2a%20rare%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22gate%20%2a%20raring%22&oq=%22gate%20%2a%20raring%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_l=serp.3...3051.10991.2.11331.36.33.0.0.0.15.259.5734.0j27j6.33.0.eish.1.0.0.2m5TYuhdosQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=b8a6da168f647da3&biw=1280&bih=705) as you might think.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/30815241@N03/2999908450 It is not all that uncommon for a racehorse or two to rear up as they're loading them into the starting gate. Those horses just want out of those stalls; sometimes they are literally raring to go. (And those jockeys are surely either brave or nuts!)

Answer (score 5):

The adjective raring is derived from rear, and means to raise up.  Used in the context you described, it would, as mentioned by Andrew Leach, denote eagerness or enthusiasm.

Answer (score -5):

This is dumb.  It's rearing.  Horses at the gate, uncomfortable with the idea of being stuffed in a box, rear up, get up on their hind legs, in protest.

Comment: No. It's really not.